# Когда имеет смысл использовать паттерны Virgil Dobjanschi? (Android REST API)

Tags: android, api, rest

Прочел много статей о том как важно использовать эти паттерны, но встречаю часто приложения, которые написаны например с помощью RETROFIT + OKHTTP, без применения данных паттернов. Не могу понять когда и в каких случаях стоит обратить внимание на эти паттерны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто что-то изредка спросить у REST-сервиса, или что-то ему отправить, то стоит использовать всякие RETROFITы и не усложнять все это дело.

А все эти паттерны стоит использовать, если вы пишете какой-то довольно сложный клиент и синхронизацией данных, полноценным локальным кэшем и т д.

Например: Допустим Вконтакте у нас RESTfull (на самом деле там солянка из http-запросов).

Тогда если вы пишете приложение, которому нужно просто проверить, онлайн ли человек ВК, то просто используйте Retrofit без всяких паттернов.

А если вы пишете полноценный клиент, где нужно хранить в локальной базе старые данные, в активите показывать, какие данные старые, а какие обновленные, там же показаны отправлен ли коммент или "в очереди", тот тут стоит задуматься над семи паттернами.

К стати те же Retrofit и OkHttp тоже компоненты в этих паттернах (блок "Rest method").